# Optimization of one input in an ML model to maximize total predictions

Tags: python, r, optimization, nonlinear-optimization

I want to run an optimization problem over this simple model on mtcars dataset that predicts mpg given the other numerical features. The idea is to use the built model as the objective function and we want to find the optimal values for cyl over the training set such that the total sum of predictions of mpg for that training set is maximized.

So set up of problem would be say allocate cyl values that could range from 2 to 10 (integer) and a constraint exists where the total sum of allocated cyl is say 50 that maximizes total 'pred' (or total mpg on the training set)?

Was looking at optim function but wasn't sure it would work here.

```r
data(mtcars)
head(mtcars)
library(xgboost)

# create model
bst = xgboost(data=as.matrix(mtcars[,-1]),label=mtcars[,1],
              objective='reg:linear',nrounds=5)

pred = predict(bst,as.matrix(mtcars[,-1]))
```

Direction to any appropriate packages in Python or R or small working solution in either language would be great.